# How to solve the calling the web services again and again when i press the activity again?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-webview

In my application first I am displaying home activity .in home activity I am getting the value from webservice and parse the value and display to user .from the home activity user click it will display to article display activity.from artcile display activity if user click it will come again home activity .It again and again calling web services and parsing the value it take time .

How to store the webservice parsed value in firsttime and get the value for all activty.Instead of calling again and again webservice can anybody give example?

Comment: Set boolean variable initializated and check it in onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

Can u show a small snippet of your code showing from where you are calling the service.

Also note

The `onCreate` method in service runs only once till the entire life of service. However, calls to `onStartCommand` method can be made multiple times by calling `startService`. If your service is destroyed and then run again, the `onCreate` will be called again.

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) is what this document tells:

```
onCreate()
```

The system calls this method when the service is first created, to perform one-time setup procedures (before it calls either `onStartCommand()` or `onBind()`). If the service is already running, this method is not called.

Comment: i am using the webservices(xml).i am getting the data from services.how to use the service without hitting the server again and again?when i start activity from b to a?

Answer (score 0):

have a boolean set when you get the response for the 1st time. And always check for the variable before calling the webservice.

Also store the response value in Application class variable or a static/non-static variable in your activity.

```
boolean callWebService = true;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //your code here

    if(callWebService){
        //call webservice in background thread -> Async Task, Service, whatever
        callWebService = false;
    }else{
        //process stored response
    }

}
```

Also keep in mind config changes if not handled will destroy the activity and call onCreate again. Handle those scenarios as well.

Hope this helps.